# SQL Switch even/odd values of the selection

Tags: mysql, sql, switch-statement

Currently I have this selection from 2 tables:

```
(SELECT e.id, e.num, '1' as TBL
FROM events e
)

UNION ALL

(SELECT p.id, p.num, '2' as TBL
FROM places p
)

ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

It returns values ordered by `num` like this:

```
id  |  num  |  TBL
 3  |    9  |    2
 1  |    8  |    2
 4  |    7  |    1
 1  |    4  |    1
 7  |    1  |    2
```

But my goal is to mix tables in selection not losing `ORDER` within a specific table. Like this:

```
id  |  num  |  TBL
 3  |    9  |    2
 4  |    7  |    1
 1  |    8  |    2
 1  |    4  |    1
 7  |    1  |    2
```

Thanks in advance! I appreciate ANY help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interleave the tables, you will need additional information.  If you enumerate each row, then you can use that for sorting.  Something like this:

```
(SELECT e.id, e.num, '1' as TBL, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn
 FROM events e CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @rn1 := 0) vars
 ORDER BY e.num desc
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT p.id, p.num, '2' as TBL, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn
 FROM places p CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @rn2 := 0) vars
 ORDER BY p.num desc
)
ORDER BY rn, tbl desc;
```

Comment: thanks so much for quick answer! It's all fine, except `ORDER`. Somehow it orders by `id` field in ascending order.

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  I don't see how it would do that.

Comment: Solved sorting problem by incapsulating each selection before and after `UNION` with `(SELECT * FROM (/selection/) AS table1)`. Gordon Linoff, thank you very much! It's a great answer! You helped me A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`DECLARE @t TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY,id INT,TBL INT)`

INSERT INTO @t (id, TBL)
SELECT id,1 FROM events
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT id,2 FROM places

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY,num numeric(18,2))

INSERT INTO @t2 (num)
(
SELECT  num 
FROM events
UNION ALL
SELECT  num 
FROM places)
ORDER BY num DESC

SELECT id, num, TBL
FROM @t a
JOIN @t2 b ON a.rn = b.rn